# Syntax error when using << but not when using +=

Tags: ruby, syntax, syntax-error

On `ruby 1.8.7`

Why this is ok:

```
string += method "value"
```

But this raise a syntax error:

```
string << method "remove reviewer"
```

Is the same behaviour in newer versions of ruby?

Comment: yeah, same behaviour in the higher version of Ruby as well. (I tested on Ruby 2.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explain this behaviour with the different [Operator Precedence](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence) of `<<` and `=+` and method calls.

Ruby reads your first examples as:

```
string += (method "value")
```

but the second one as:

```
(string << method) "remove reviewer"
```

IMO it is a good practice to use parenthesize for method call even if Ruby does not need them in many case. This makes the code more readable and less error-prone:

```
string += method("value")
string << method("remove reviewer")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, same behaviour in the higher version of Ruby as well. (I tested on Ruby 2.2).

It's because of Ruby's [operator precedence](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#table_18.4).

To get around this, you can use parentheses in case of `<<`:

```
string << method("remove reviewer")
```

Then, it should work and won't get the syntax error.

Or, to make it consistent, you can use parentheses for both of them:

```
string += method("value")
string << method("remove reviewer")
```

**Infact, it is highly recommended to use parentheses `()` for method calls to avoid such situations like the one you're asking about.** Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722369/whats-the-precedence-of-rubys-method-call) for some more information.