# Why does this statement act like this? (puts("here") && break) vs (puts "here" && break)

Tags: ruby

statement 1:

```
[2,4,6,7,8].each do |i|
    (i % 2 == 0) || (puts "Not even" && break)
    puts i
end
```

statement 2:

```
[2,4,6,7,8].each do |i|
    (i % 2 == 0) || (puts("not even") && break)
    puts i
end
```

Statement 1 breaks but doesn't put, and statement 2 puts but doesn't break

Why does it behave this way, and how could I write this expression better? (I don't mean finding odd #s, I mean ||  && statements)

Comment: In either case, you are writing non-idiomatic Ruby code. Code should be easily read and understood. Any time it can't be quickly grasped it needs to be refactored to be simpler. Complex, convoluted, or obfuscated code is a maintenance nightmare and very often a bug in waiting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Statement 1:**

Ruby interprets it like this: `puts("Not even" && break)`.
So `break` is executed before `puts` argument is parsed.

---

**Statement 2:**

`puts("not even")` returns `nil` and so `break` is not executed at all

---

If you realy want it to be inline I'd suggest writing this without `&&`: `(puts "Not even"; break)`

Answer (score 4):

> how could I write this expression better

Don't [write expressions where you mean to use flow-control statements].

Using boolean expressions for flow-control like that is fragile at best. And, more likely, is just confusing and hard to understand. Compare to this, for example.

```
[2,4,6,7,8].each do |i|
  if i % 2 != 0 # if i.odd?
    puts 'not even'
    break
  end

  puts i
end
```

Which style to choose, depends on what you're after: readability or terseness. If you're not participating in code golf, I'd say, choose readability every time.

Comment: 'Zactly! The OPs code is something that'd get flagged in a code review in an instant. Ugh.

Answer (score 3):

`puts "Not even" && break` is equal to `puts("Not even" && break)`, break will be executed, so the loop will break.

`puts("not even")` will return `nil`.

`puts("not even") && break` is equal to: `nil && break`, break isn't executed, so the loop doesn't break.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that [function application has a lower precedence than any operators in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722369/whats-the-precedence-of-rubys-method-call).

So

```
puts "Not even" && break
```

becomes

```
puts ("Not even" && break)
```

(the `&&` is evaluated before the function call). See also [Ruby operator precedence](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html)

Comment: To avoid this, use `and` instead of `&&`, which has a much lower operator precedence.

Comment: @mhutter In my experience, relying on operator precedence is always a bad idea (apart from the most obvious cases). Better use parentheses when there's the slightest doubt - even if you exactly know what a given expression does, the next programmer (which might very well be yourself in a couple of months/years) might not know the rules as good as you.

Comment: Yes I absolutely agree but I felt it had to be mentioned for completeness :-)